# Prove by induction that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j(j+1)} = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$

Tags: summation, induction

I am currently trying to get this down but for some reason cannot seem to understand what I am doing wrong here. Here is what I have done so far

*Proof*: By induction on $n$.

*Base Case*: $n = 1$. This is trivial.

*Inductive Step*: Suppose for $k \geq 1$ that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{j(j+1)} = 1 - \frac{1}{k + 1}$. We show that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{j(j+1)} = 1 - \frac{1}{(k+1) + 1}$. Observe that
$$\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{j(j+1)} &= \sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{j(j+1)} + \frac{1}{(k+1)((k+1) + 1)} \\
        &= 1 - \frac{1}{(k+1)} + \frac{1}{(k+1)(k + 2)} \quad\text{(by inductive hypothesis)}\\
        &= 1 - \frac{k + 2 + 1}{(k+1)(k + 2)} \\ 
        &= 1 - \frac{2}{(k + 2)}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}$$
As observed, the numerator differs only by 1 value. There's got to be some algebra I am messing up.

If I could get some help on where I am messing up, that would be great thanks!

Comment: $$1 - \frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} = 1- \frac{k+2-1}{(k+1)(k+2)} = 1 - \frac{k+1}{(k+1)(k+2)} = 1 - \frac{1}{k+2}$$

Comment: Last line. You cancelled a k+3 with a k+1

Comment: My goodness, thank you. I need to not make such mistakes in algebra :(

Comment: @Owen it's always the little things :P

Comment: The story gets simpler if you write$$\frac 1{j(j+1)}=\frac 1j-\frac1{j+1}\ ,$$ the telescope is clear, but also the inductive step, if this must be for imposed didactical reasons... (They have a principle in chess: *If you see a good move, look for a better one*... Here, *if you see a good proof, look for a better one*...)

Comment: @dan_fulea I did not even notice it was the telescoping series. I have not seen it in a while.